# Excluding when X exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, exists

I have a list of ID’s, each id has a code and a date.   There can be multiple codes and dates for each ID.  I need to find the ID’s that only include code X and code Y (code in (X,Y)) as well as a date older than 540 days ago `(Date <= DATEADD(dd, -540, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))`.

Since an ID can have multiple codes and dates I need to exclude those ID’s that do not match my criteria above.  Below is an example of this.

```
  ID   Code Date

  5525  X   2010-10-07 
  5525  Y   2010-11-25 
  5525  Y   2010-11-29 
  5525  Y   2010-10-06 
**5525  X   2011-01-14** 
**5525  X   2011-01-31**
  5525  Y   2010-12-09
  5525  Y   2010-10-15 
  5525  X   2010-10-18 
  5525  Y   2010-12-08 
  5525  X   2010-12-09
```

---

Because the two highlighted ID’s have a date that is greater than -540 days ago I need to exclude all ID’s even if it meets my original criteria.

I need to include ID's that meets my criteria `(code in (X,Y) and Date <= DATEADD(dd, -540, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))`, but not if another ID of the same value does not meet this criteria.

```
select ID from table
where code in (X,Y)
and date <= DATEADD(dd, -540, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: What are you using for a database?

Comment: Thanks, for future reference including a tag for the technology being used is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are after something like this:

```
SELECT t1.ID FROM table_x t1
 WHERE 
    t1.Date <= DATEADD(dd, -540, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND
    -- you can add other criterias here as well, like t1.Code in (X,Y)
    t1.ID NOT IN (
       SELECT ID FROM table_x t2
        WHERE 
          t2.Date > DATEADD(dd, -540, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
          -- you can add other criterias here as well, like t2.Code in (Z,F) 
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `NOT IN` clause together with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM table1
    WHERE Date <= DATEADD(dd, -540, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)    
)
AND code in ('X','Y')
```

Does this help?

P.S. It's quite "anti-standard" to call a field `ID` when it is not unique across the table. I admit it did confuse me a bit.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful.  I was using "ID" to obfuscate my data.  I apologize for the confusion, this is my first post on this site and i am a newbie.  Thank you for your time.  I am going to test this now....

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE id IN ( 
    SELECT id  
    FROM table1 
    WHERE Date <= DATEADD(dd, -540, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)     
    AND code in ('X','Y')
    )
AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT id  
    FROM table1 
    WHERE Date > DATEADD(dd, -540, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)     
    AND code in ('X','Y')
    )
AND Date != '0001-01-01'


Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @user1370407 Great! Now kindly mark my answer as helpful or correct.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check that a given ID satisfies your conditions for all instances, do a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` with the inverse of your criteria. Like so:

```
SELECT ID, Code, [Date]
FROM tablename t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tablename
    WHERE ID = t.ID AND NOT (
        Code IN ('X','Y')
        AND [Date] <= DATEADD(dd, -540, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
)
```